# How to handle paged param in post and custom-post-type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, pagination

hope someone can help me on my customization.

PREMISES i'm very experienced dev, but very beginner on wp.
I readed lot of answer on SO but not finding nothing similar to solve my issue.

What i need for my customization is:
read $paged param inside normal post type and cutom-post-type.

I handle single.php and single-mytype.php only with custom php code, so i'm not using any loop or other wp-query (data come from external db).

What i need is: 
When i use `get_pagenum_link($p)` on post or cpt i obviosully get the right fancy url.

inside post (single.php)
the a href (from `get_pagenum_link($p)`) will show

```
https://domain.com/post-title/page/2/
```

inside custom-post-type 
the a href (from `get_pagenum_link($p)`) will show

```
https://domain.com/custom-post-type/page-name/page/2/
```

Those urls are exactly what i need, but on both if i try to follow link, i always get redirect to main url:

```
https://domain.com/post-title/
https://domain.com/custom-post-type/page-name/
```

If instead of `get_pagenum_link($p)` i use other param like `add_query_arg(array('pg' => $p), home_url($wp->request).'/')` everythings will work well (but ugly url).

I would like to keep using seo friendly urls structure.

NOTE 
I have tried to register manually  my-custom-post-type with 'page' and 'hierarchical' attribute, and also with
WCK Post Type Creator plugin created with following options
[image]

I have also tried (to force) to handle the paged param on function.php like this

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ($q){
  if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() &&
        (is_post_type_archive( 'post' ) || is_post_type_archive( 'ads' ))

  ) {
    $q->set( 'paged', '1' );
  }
});
```

Any help how to solve this, i only need $paged be accessible on both post and cpt.

Thanks to all guys.

Comment: `paged` is the query var for post archives. Singular posts use the `page` query var, and the URL format is `https://domain.com/post-title/2/`, without `page`. You'll find that these URLs won't redirect.